# Pygame: Can someone help me implement double jumping?

Tags: python, pygame

I know there are already other posts about this out there, but my movement system is a little from the ones that I have found, so subsequently I am asking this question.

My movement system is based on a named tuple called `Move(up,left,right,down)`
Then there is this:

```
def update(self, move, blocks):
    # check if we can jump 
    if move.up and self.on_ground:
        self.yvel -= self.jump_speed
    # simple left/right movement
    if move.left:
            self.xvel = -self.move_speed
    if move.right:
            self.xvel = self.move_speed

    # if in the air, fall down
    if not self.on_ground:
        self.yvel += 0.3
        # but not too fast
        if self.yvel > max_gravity: self.yvel = max_gravity

    # if no left/right movement, x speed is 0, of course
    if not (move.left or move.right):
        self.xvel = 0

    # move horizontal, and check for horizontal collisions
    self.rect.left += self.xvel
    self.collide(self.xvel, 0, blocks)

    # move vertically, and check for vertical collisions
    self.rect.top += self.yvel
    self.on_ground = False
    self.collide(0, self.yvel, blocks)

def collide(self, xvel, yvel, blocks):
    # all blocks that we collide with
    for block in [blocks[i] for i in self.rect.collidelistall(blocks)]:

        # if xvel is > 0, we know our right side bumped 
        # into the left side of a block etc.
        if xvel > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left;self.xvel=0
        if xvel < 0:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right;self.xvel=0

        # if yvel > 0, we are falling, so if a collision happpens 
        # we know we hit the ground (remember, we seperated checking for
        # horizontal and vertical collision, so if yvel != 0, xvel is 0)
        if yvel > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            self.on_ground = True
            self.yvel = 0
        # if yvel < 0 and a collision occurs, we bumped our head
        # on a block above us
        if yvel < 0: self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom;self.yvel=0
```

I tried adding a fifth variable to the tuple called `upUp`, and when that was called it would trigger another jump, regardless of if `on_ground` was true or not.

To trigger it I used this in the event loop:

```
if e.type==KEYUP:
    if dj==0:
        dj=-1
    if dj=-1:
        dj='true'
Move(K_w,K_a,K_d,K_s,dj)
```

But this didn't work well at all!
Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~chin/215S10/Assignments/A8/gameSprites.py This may be an implementation of it from a quick glance.

Comment: There is also a full working version (*just test*) of Super Mario Bros using pygame: http://www.pygame.org/project-Super+Mario+Python+Beta-1339-4650.html -- It has *Hold Z to increase air time while jumping*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to maintain some kind of state to keep track of which "phase" of jumping you're in.

These "phases" are:

- on ground
- do jump (jump-button pressed)
- jumping and in mid-air (jump-button released)
- double-jump (jump-button pressed again)

So you should be able to do something like:

```
def update(self, move, blocks):
    if self.on_ground:
        self.jump_state = 'on_ground'

    if move.up and self.on_ground:
        # jump!
        self.yvel -= self.jump_speed
        self.jump_state = 'jumped'

    if self.jump_state = 'jumped' and not move.up and not self.on_ground:
        self.jump_state = 'ready_for_double_jump'

    if self.jump_state = 'ready_for_double_jump' and move.up:
        # jump!
        self.yvel -= self.jump_speed
        self.jump_state = 'double_jumped'

    ...
```

You'll get the idea.