# Unity - Make Character Be Able To Jump When Slide Off the Platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D endless platform runner game in Unity based on the code shown in [this](https://youtu.be/PlT44xr0iW0) video and I am not able to figure out how to make a character be able to jump if slide off the platform.

In the code the jumping is controlled by checking if the player has a platform below him when pressed space. So when the character slide off the platform, he has nothing below and cannot jump.

I figured out how to make the character double jump but cannot come with solution to the falling. Everything I tried made the character jump endlessly.

I don't know how to make character be able to jump when falling after slide of the platform (so the character has not jumped yet before fall).

Ok so here is the code:

```
public void OnJumpInputDown() {
    if (controller.collisions.below) {
            velocity.y = maxJumpVelocity;
            doubleJump = true;
        }
    } else if (doubleJump)
    {
        doubleJump = false;
        velocity.y = maxJumpVelocity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame: Can someone help me implement double jumping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610845/pygame-can-someone-help-me-implement-double-jumping)

Comment: How did you implement your double jump? You could use that as a start for this

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post any specific piece of code, I will only give you a general answer. What you need to do is create another condition, and when the player has nothing below him, you need to make sure whether or not he is sliding off the platform. A possible example would be to create a boolean that becomes true as soon as he is sliding, and so if there is nothing below him but that boolean is true then he can still jump, otherwise there is nothing below him and he cant jump.

Comment: I have the same code as shown in the end of that video I linked. Also the player is still, I did not meant sliding like a movement but when he walks off the platform without jumping. Then he cannot jump. I tried to solve it with a bool but then he can jump endlessly.

Comment: That means ur forgetting to turn the bool back to false once he has stopped sliding, try the same thing with the bool but careful to set it back to false when the player is back to original condition, since it seems like u just set it it to true.

Comment: It would not really work with that as it is controlled by checking if the player stands on something when the space was pressed. And when he is not then he cannot jump (except the double jump). So there is not a way how to control the falling conditions as he falls when he jumped and he falls the same when he slide of the platform. But I figured it out already today, I post it below. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out today and I added a variable that remembers how many jumps the player has available and when he touch the ground it resets if the player is not already jumping. :) Here is the code:

```
int hasJumps;
bool jumping;

public void OnJumpInputDown() {
    jumping = true;
    if (controller.collisions.below) {
         velocity.y = maxJumpVelocity;
         hasJumps = hasJumps - 1;
    } else if (hasJumps != 0) {
        velocity.y = maxJumpVelocity;
        hasJumps = hasJumps - 1;
    }
}

public void OnJumpInputUp() {
    jumping = false;
}


void IsFalling()
{
    if ((controller.collisions.below) && (!jumping))
    {
        hasJumps = 2;
    }
}
```